# 403 from S3 despite allowing "s3:GetObject" action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-serverless

I'm using Serverless to deploy my Lambda functions to AWS, one of which reads S3 objects. I have these permissions set up in my `serverless.yml` file:

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:ListBucket
        - s3:GetObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"
```

However, after deploying the API, when I try to hit the endpoint Serverless gives me, I get a 403. I also went into IAM in the AWS console to check the lambdaRole for the applicable region and for S3, I see an "Access Level" of "Limited: List". My understanding is that I should see "Read" here as well based on the actions I am allowing.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetObject` action operates on objects, not on buckets, so your policy is incorrect. Try the following:

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - s3:ListBucket
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - s3:GetObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
```